# How to compare columns of a binary matrix and compare elements in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, row

i have [sentences*words] matrix as shown below

```
out = 0 1 1 0 1
      1 1 0 0 1
      1 0 1 1 0
      0 0 0 1 0
```

i want to process this matrix in a way that should tell `W1` & `W2` in "sentence number 2" and "sentence number 4" occurs with same value i.e `1 1` and `0 0`.the output should be as follows:

```
output{1,2}= 2 4
```

output{1,2} tells word number 1 and 2 occurs in sentence number 2 and 4 with same values.

after comparing `W1` & `W2` next candidate should be `W1` & `W3` which occurs with same value in `sentence 3` & `sentence 4`

```
output{1,3}= 3 4
```

and so on till every `nth` word is compared with every other words and saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a logical matrix of size #words-by-#words-by-#sentences easily using [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun):

```
coc = bsxfun( @eq, permute( out, [3 2 1]), permute( out, [2 3 1] ) );
```

this logical array is `occ( wi, wj, si )` is true iff word `wi` and word `wj` occur in sentence `si` with the same value.

To get the `output` cell array from `coc` you need

```
nw = size( out, 2 ); %// number of words
output = cell(nw,nw);
for wi = 1:(nw-1)
    for wj = (wi+1):nw
        output{wi,wj} = find( coc(wi,wj,:) );
        output{wj,wi} = output{wi,wj}; %// you can force it to be symmetric if you want
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i wanted to ask what does `[3 2 1]` do in `bsxfun` function secondly i want to apply this operation on [N*M] matrix where sentences and words logical matrix differs in sizez in different cases. can i run this code on any dimensions of [sentences cross words matrix] ?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad (1) `[3 2 1]` argument is not of `bsxfun` directly but for `permute`, please read the documentation of `permute` to better understand the solution. This answer should work on any 2D `out` matrix.

Comment: okay, and what if i want to display `output` in a single line rather than in column format in separate lines, i've tried `celldisp(output)` but it gives output consisting on several lines i need to display as follows `for example` `output{1,2}= 1 3 4,...`

Answer (score 2):

This would be one `vectorized` approach -

```
%// Get number of columns in input array for later usage 
N = size(out,2);

%//  Get indices for pairwise combinations between columns of input array
[idx2,idx1] = find(bsxfun(@gt,[1:N]',[1:N])); %//'

%// Get indices for matches between out1 and out2. The row indices would
%// represent the occurance values for the final output and columns for the 
%// indices of the final output.
[R,C] = find(out(:,idx1) == out(:,idx2))

%// Form cells off each unique C (these will be final output values)
output_vals = accumarray(C(:),R(:),[],@(x) {x})

%// Setup output cell array
output = cell(N,N)

%// Indices for places in output cell array where occurance values are to be put
all_idx = sub2ind(size(output),idx1,idx2)

%// Finally store the output values at appropriate indices
output(all_idx(1:max(C))) = output_vals
```